# Learning Assessment/ Quiz and Review Web Part

Tags: web-part

I need to create an instructional review for a week long class, sortable by the subject or block of instruction that will be originally deployed on SP2010 but will be easily compatible with 2013 when the site migrates. I know there's a few ways to create it, just curious what you might think would be the BEST way to go about it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say create a survey list for questions, then have some javascript that will use CSOM or an Event Receiver to pull from an "answers" list that will check the work of each user whenever the user takes the quiz (survey). Then you can score the user in ANOTHER list that has a view that is only viewable to him/her.

- **List 1 - Survey List**

  - Will list all the questions
  - Change setting in advanced setting to only allow viewing of their own addition/changes
- **List 2 - Answers List**

  - Simple list that houses all the answers per quiz.
  - One item will show all answers in order, maybe separated by comma
- **List 3 - Score List**

  - List that displays three fields, User, Quiz ID, Score
  - Will create one item per user/per quiz

JavaScript/Event Receiver will trigger on new survey addition, that will check values of List 1 values against List 2, then create a new item on List 3 displaying the score when done.